# How to show 5 columns from TABLE A, then 2 columns from Table B, then remaining coulmns from Table A again in a sql server join

Tags: php, sql

How to show 5 columns from TABLE A, then 2 columns from Table B, then remaining coulmns from Table A again in a sql server join .

Follwing is my query.

SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.local_time, B.creation_time FROM #SqlData A 
        INNER JOIN @OracleInfo B ON A.event_id = B.GLOBALEVENTID

this order is specifically required to keep the similar columns together. And both the tables have really large number of columns. so i don't want to name them directly.

Please help me out.

Comment: Why is the order of the columns even important? I'd suggest using `AS` and fetching the results based on aliases.

Comment: The column position in the resultset shouldn't have any impact. Could you elaborate why you need this?

Comment: this order is specifically required to keep the similar columns together. And both the tables have really large number of columns. so i don't want to name them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT A.COL1,A.COL2,A.COL3,A.COL4,A.COL5, B.local_time, B.creation_time, A.COL6, A.COL7, A.COLN FROM #SqlData A INNER JOIN @OracleInfo B ON A.event_id = B.GLOBALEVENTID
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specifically mention column names in SELECT list. This can,t be done using * in select list which selects all the columns.